# JSON Replacing '.' with

Tags: java, json, replace

I want a Program which takes JSON file as input and Results JSON file. The input file contains like:

```
{"empname":"surname.firstname","department.name":"production","salary":11254.42}
```

The Output file must replace '.'(dot) with '_'(underscore) of the input JSON.
The expecting Output:

```
{"empname":"surname_firstname","department_name":"production","salary":11254_42}
```

I want this program using JAVA, without using Serialization and Deserialization. Can any one help?

Comment: Your output is invalid json because 11254_42 is no-longer a valid number.

Comment: Do you actually just want to change the dots to underscores in property names or values that are that are stings?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 7+:

```
String str = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("in.json")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .replace('.', '_');

Files.write(Paths.get("out.json"), str.getBytes("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
```

Comment: This does what the OP is asking for but the output is not valid json because it converts decimal points in values of type number to underscores.

Comment: You're right. :) Let us hope that the OP provide more details.

Comment: In fact in the OP's example points in numbers are converted to _ just like any other dot